# Find missing datapoints in time sequence

Tags: sql, amazon-timestream

I have datapoints with 15 minutes

```
counting_point        time.                           value
AT100                 2024-01-03 23:00:00.000000000.  100
AT100                 2024-01-03 23:15:00.000000000.  120
AT100                 2024-01-03 23:45:00.000000000.  122
```

Now i have the problem that the datapoint with time `2024-01-03 23:30:00.000000000` is missing.

How can i write a sql query to detect this missing fields? There can be multiple missing fields

Comment: How do you decide what times should be present, can you give the exact calculation? Is it just "start at a certain hour, add 15 minutes until another hour"? Or are you just looking at the data and determining there is a gap of more than 15 minutes? Or does the data itself somehow tell you how big the gap to look for is (how would that even work)?

Comment: @Charlieface The data is always in 15 minutes steps. What i want is to tell i have a start and an end date. example start would be `2024-01-02 00:00:00.000000000` and end is `2024-01-04 00:00:00.000000000` that should be 192 datapoints because 24h multiplied by 15 minutes is 96, multiplied by 2 days is 192. Now it can be that there is an gap like in this example `2024-01-03 23:30:00.000000000` is missing, or maybe multiple datapoints are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Each time there is an operation to be scheduled on a regular basis (every day or every hour or every 15 minutes...) it is necessary that your data model contain a planning table with all the point entries over time without discontinuities.

As an example, I create the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE T_SCHEDULE_SCH (SCH_TIME TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY);
WITH 
T AS (SELECT CAST('2024-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP) AS PIT
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT PIT + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE 
      FROM   T
      WHERE  PIT < '2033-12-31 23:59:00')
SELECT *
FROM   T;
```

Then the final query is trivial...

```
SELECT PIT
FROM   T_SCHEDULE_SCH 
EXCEPT
SELECT "time" 
FROM   datapoints;
```